# C# Monotouch/Xamarin.iOS - Import Calendar Content

Tags: c#, import, xamarin.ios, calendar

How do I import the calendar from my iPhone into my app so that I can work with the data?

I'm using C# Montouch/Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EventKit](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_eventkit/).

First, you have to request access to the Calendar:

```
EKEventStore EventStore = new EKEventStore();
EventStore.RequestAccess (EKEntityType.Event, 
        (bool granted, NSError e) => {
                if (granted)
                        //do something here
                else
                        new UIAlertView ( "Access Denied", 
"User Denied Access to Calendar Data", null,
"ok", null).Show ();
                } );
```

To query all events in a timeframe, do something like this:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays ( -7 );
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
// the third parameter is calendars we want to look in, to use all calendars, we pass null
NSPredicate query = App.Current.EventStore.PredicateForEvents ( startDate, endDate, null );

// execute the query
EKCalendarItem[] events = App.Current.EventStore.EventsMatching ( query );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Xamarin.Mobile. This would be cross-platform.

Example from the [api docs](http://xamarin.com/mobileapi):

```cs
var abook = new AddressBook();
abook.RequestPermissions().ContinueWith (t =>
{
    if (!t.Result)
        return; // Permission denied

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Full LINQ support
    foreach (Contact c in abook.Where (c => c.FirstName == "Eric" && c.Phones.Any()))
    {
        builder.AppendLine (c.DisplayName);
        foreach (Phone p in c.Phones)
            builder.AppendLine (String.Format ("{0}: {1}", p.Label, p.Number));

        builder.AppendLine();
    }

    contacts.Text = builder.ToString(); // Update UI

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // Ensure we're on the UI Thread
```